# How can I Optimise the performance of a Composable image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have an `Image` composable Im using as a background. How can I optimise this? I know you can use the graphics layer for vectors but this is using a drawable from a png file unfortunately and is not a vector

```
MainScreen() {
...
scaffold() { innerPadding -> 
           Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .fillMaxSize(),
            ) {
                val painter = painterResource(id = themeDrawableRes)
                // background
                Image(
                    painter = painter,
                    contentDescription = "null",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .matchParentSize(),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
                )
...
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: this looks optimal, do you have performance problems with that?

Comment: Its kinda wanna make its recompositions skippable. Just to improve a bit of jank Im having. Its recomposing with a slider I have set up. but no worries if this is the best I can do with it thanks!